# Where were the early kings of Scotland buried?

Tags: royalty, scotland

According to tradition and to most historians until recently, many of the early Scottish kings were buried on the island of Iona. For example, the 2004 *[Oxford Dictionary of National Biography](https://www.oxforddnb.com/view/10.1093/ref:odnb/9780198614128.001.0001/odnb-9780198614128-e-15398?rskey=KznWPg&result=1)*<sup>paywall</sup> entry for Kenneth I or Kenneth Macalpine (d. 858) by Marjorie Anderson states that

> "he and most of his successors down to the eleventh century are said by lists to have been buried in Iona."

One of these successors was Macbeth.

On a visit to Iona last week, however, I found virtually no mention of these kings (not so much as their names), and just a bare statement that recent historical research has made it doubtful that they are buried there. The name of James Earle Fraser (University of Guelph) seems to be significant, and particularly Fraser's paper "[Iona and the burial places of the kings of Alba](https://onlinesales.admin.cam.ac.uk/product-catalogue/products/schools-faculties-departments-and-institutions/anglo-saxon-norse-celtic-publications/kathleen-hughes-memorial-lectures/iona-and-the-burial-places-of-the-kings-of-alba)" (2016). This paper is not available on the internet, however, and nor have I been able to find any discussion on the question. It seems odd that such an ancient tradition should be abandoned with so little discussion.

Can anyone point me to discussion, and, specifically, can anyone say where "recent historical research" now locates the graves of these kings?

**Edit:** The notice in the graveyard had a single sentence but I didn't photograph it. The guidebook (2015) says a little more. It mentions Reilig Odhrain as the legendary burial place of early Scottish kings and then says "However, there is not much evidence to back up this tradition. It may have arisen through a misunderstanding of the records, or perhaps through royal propaganda. Alexander I may have sought to create a distinction between the "old" line of kings, ending with his uncle Donald Ban, with Iona as their mausoleum and the "new" dynasty beginning with Alexander's parents Malcolm and Margaret, buried at Dunfermline."

The guidebook predates the Fraser paper referred to above, and references an earlier unpublished paper: J. Fraser, 'Alexander I, Dunfermline and the Mausoleum of the Gaelic Kings of Scotland in Iona', (2010).

Here is what appears to be the abstract of this paper:

"The famous island of Iona looms large in the history of Gaelic Scotland and is widely believed to have been home to a mausoleum in which the remains of the kings of the Gaelic realms of Dál Riata and Alba were buried. The body of surviving early medieval evidence pertaining to Iona provides no convincing support for this belief, which was nevertheless held to be true throughout the central and later Middle Ages. In the sixteenth century Donald Monro was even capable of visiting and describing a ‘Tomb of stanes’ in Iona marked Tumulus Regum Scotiae, Grave of the Kings of Scotland. Historians however have long known, or at least suspected, that Iona’s royal mausoleum was a fabrication of later times. This paper traces the origins of the idea to a single document: a king-list written, probably at St Andrews, during the reign of King Alexander I (1107-24). In considering motives for imagining in these years that Iona contained a burial ground of early Scottish kings, the paper unearths some intriguing evidence about how Alexander viewed Scottish kingship in the days of the Alpínid kings (842-1058): ideas that influenced perceptions of early Scottish history for many centuries to come. The paper also reflects on evidence, some of which is Irish in provenance, which may give an indication of the actual resting places of several of the Gaelic kings of Scotland."

Comment: Can you give us any more info on what was presented there besides Fraser? (Since Fraser's _lecture_ is indeed nowhere to be found, not even for good money, [just some 'enthusiastic listeners' testimonial](https://issuu.com/hugheshall/docs/hughes_magazine_issue_22_web-1) I'd _almost insist_ that someone mail him stern demands to upload that somewhere…or publish it properly) // Could you add the timeframe; which kings are of interest (assuming this inteerst 'ends' with Macbethad)?

Comment: @LangLangC The **paper** does appear to be published, by Cambridge, albeit pretty expensive at £6 for 31 pages! I don't understand your reference to an *enthusiastic listener*, maybe I'm missing something?  https://onlinesales.admin.cam.ac.uk/product-catalogue/products/schools-faculties-departments-and-institutions/anglo-saxon-norse-celtic-publications/kathleen-hughes-memorial-lectures/iona-and-the-burial-places-of-the-kings-of-alba

Comment: @TheHonRose It seems to be out of stock, though, and unavailable on all the usual new and secondhand sites.

Comment: @TheHonRose That outlet won't let me make transactions (even at that laughable price) while others do list it and then continue to claim "unavailable"/["out of stock"](https://blackwells.co.uk/bookshop/product/Iona-and-the-Burial-Places-of-the-Kings-of-Alba-by-James-E-Fraser-University-of-Cambridge-issuing-body/9781909106109)… What you seem to miss is the 'testimonial' from the Hughes-magazine (p13).

Comment: Please [edit] additional info into the Q. (Given Fraser's _available_ work & its titles, incl that Hughes mag, "propaganda" is indeed a likely content part of the mysterious paper. We could stubble together that from other latest sources and in essence retrace that work based on that… Some info on a few kings is contradictory and much later nationalist historiography made that even worse… keyword: "Invented tradition"But hopefully a few more succinct papers surface on this.)

Comment: Libraries that [hold Fraser's lecture](https://www.worldcat.org/title/iona-and-the-burial-places-of-the-kings-of-alba/oclc/962820986). When done editing, please flag my comments here as 'no longer needed'.

Comment: And libraries that [hold the series/journal](https://www.worldcat.org/title/kathleen-hughes-memorial-lectures-on-mediaeval-welsh-history/oclc/902706195&referer=brief_results) in which the lecture was published. If OP has recently visited Iona, then perhaps OP is close enough to one of these libraries to visit. Also, the [British Library](http://explore.bl.uk/BLVU1:LSCOP-ALL:BLL01010494621) seems to have an On Demand service. Possibly this or Interlibrary Loan could be used to obtain the lecture.

Comment: @LаngLаngС - apologies, not only did I "miss" it, I can't even find it :-( although to be fair I'm on my phone, and the so-called publications don't make life easy! Strange that a piece of Scottish historiography should have sunk so completely. Sic transit... ;-)

Comment: @TheHonRose Page 7, "Medieval Scottish propaganda explored"

Comment: As James Earle Fraser is an academic, presumably this one paper is not his only output on this topic. It might be instructive to visit (in person or online) an academic library and search the catalog and/or journal databases for other writings of this researcher. I found at least one book and one other paper.

Comment: @shoover Thank you.

Comment: @shoover We now have a general idea of 'why not Iona', with Fraser & others dissecting one 'inevented tradition' (eg Alexander, Frodun, Skene), criticising harmonising historiography when conflicting sources come abound and most generally favouring likely less biased Irish srcs when in doubt. While I'd favour direct access to 'that' special paper to at least compare, we could also 'reverse engineer' (most) that info now. Wan to take a leap?

Comment: @shoover Fraser does not reference either paper on his research page https://www.uoguelph.ca/arts/history/people/james-e-fraser. I think that there is probably some controversy on this subject among experts. I have not so far had a reply to an email that I sent.

Comment: I just want to point out that Iona wasn't under Scottish control during the whole period in question. The abbey was abandoned and Kenneth MacAlpin had the remaining treasures of Iona, including the relics of St  Columba, moved elsewhere because of Viking raids. It's unlikely he'd want to buried there. The Scots didn't get the Hebrides back until 1256.